# TrailheaDX 2019

Tags: discussion

Last time that I went to Dreamforce was 2017 and I totally missed that there was a SFSE meetup. Anyway I'm coming back to town for TDX 2019.

Might there be enough interest to do something at TDX?

Comment: I'm planning to be there!

Comment: I'll be there as well! We should definitely plan a SFSE meetup there.

Comment: I'll also be there.

Comment: A couple of my sessions have been accepted but depends if I will be flown to SFO from Oz. Or I might need to fly myself :)

Comment: Agenda Builder is out. Do we have any SFSEers running sessions?

Comment: Well... ? :) :)

Answer (score 2):

I will be there, just got approved! This will be my first SF conference.

Comment: congratulations on that